# Insert statement won't work, getting syntax near "?":

Tags: python, sqlite

For some reason I'm getting the error but I don't see why. I've looked up some tutorials and nothing works.

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Users (?, ?, ?, ?)''', (UUN, UUID1, UUID2, UUID3))
```

The 4 variable names are UNN, UUID1, UUID2, UUID3.

Comment: `INSERT INTO Users(<column names go here>) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`

Comment: You didn't specify `VALUES` in your query string

Comment: Follow the correct syntax: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the column names from your query. Assuming they're the same as those variable names,

```py
cursor.execute(
    'INSERT INTO Users (uun, uuid1, uuid2, uuid3) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
    (UUN, UUID1, UUID2, UUID3),
)
```